# Pine Script conditional statement syntax

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, pine-script

I struggle to code an if statement in Pine.
The idea is that the stop-loss is tightened when a waring signal is triggered.
This tighter stop should replace the regular stop-loss and trailing-stop. I hoped is was a simple syntax error, but I can't seem to fix it by editing indents and spaces. Is there something more fundamental I'm overlooking?

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

```
longLossPerc = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3.4) * 0.01 
longTrailPerc = input(title="Long Trail Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=2.5) * 0.01 
longTightStopPerc  = input(title="Long K Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.6) * 0.01 

longStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - longLossPerc)
longTrailPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - longTrailPerc) 
longTightStop = high * (1 - longTightStopPerc) 

    
stopValueLong = 0.0
if (Signal)
    stopValueLong = longTightStop
     else
       stopValueLong = max(longStopPrice, longTailPrice)
else
    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something more or less of the following form, which supposes you have state variables to know the distinction between when you are in a trade or not:

```
var stopValueLong = 0.0
if (Signal)
    stopValueLong := longTightStop
else if inTrade
    stopValueLong := max(longStopPrice, longTailPrice)
else if closeTrade
    stopValueLong := na
```

The `:=` operator is important to assign values to your `stopValueLong` variable from with an `if` statement's local scopes. See:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-assignment